# Call native method from dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, dll, c++-cli

I am trying to use `MimeTex.dll` in Mixed Mode of C++/CLI project. I include the dll by:
`#pragma comment(lib,"MimeTex.dll")`

and I tried to call this method:
`CreateGifFromEq("expression","path");`

but the compiler inform that it doesn't know CreateGifFromEq() method.

I didn't find resources in the web in how to use  `MimeTex.dll` in C++. I just find how to use it with C# in [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11406/Enable-Your-Users-to-Write-Math-Equations-in-Your) by Pinvok like:

```
[System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
internal class NativeMethods
{
    private NativeMethods()
    { //all methods in this class would be static
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("MimeTex.dll")]
    internal static extern int CreateGifFromEq(string expr, string fileName);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal extern static IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal extern static bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hLibModule);
}
```

and then call it like:

```
NativeMethods.CreateGifFromEq(equation, tempGifFilePath);
```

How I can call it without Pinvok in mixed mode of C++/CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you meant to write:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"MimeTex.lib")
```

In other words, you pass the .lib file to the linker rather than the .dll. When you compiled the DLL, a .lib file will have been generated.

But that's not your immediate problem. The compiler has no declaration for `CreateGifFromEq`. That's because you have not included the library's header file in your C++ code. Doing that should resolve the issue.

If all you need is that one function then it should be trivial to declare it in your C++ code.

```
__declspec(dllimport) extern int CreateGifFromEq(char *expr, char *fileName);
```

You probably will need to wrap that in an `extern "C"` block too.

Actually, having looked at the library, the header file that is supplied with the source does not declare that function, even though it's present in the library.

Answer (score 1):

In C++/CLI you can use P/Invoke as in C#.

If you don't want to use P/Invoke, the other way is to load the DLL with [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and get pointers to the functions with [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

Here's the equivalent of the C# code in C++/CLI:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

private ref class NativeMethods abstract sealed
{
internal:
    [DllImport("MimeTex.dll")]
    static int CreateGifFromEq(String^ expr, String^ fileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static IntPtr GetModuleHandle(String^ lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [returnvalue: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::Bool)]
    static bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hLibModule);
};
```

As you can see it's almost identical to the C# code except for some minor syntax changes.

Here's how you would use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress (which has the advantage of not requiring marshaling, which is unnecessary in C++ anyway):

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"MimeTex.dll");
int (*fpCreateGifFromEq)(WCHAR*, WCHAR*) = GetProcAddress(hModule, "CreateGifFromEq");
(*fpCreateGifFromEq)(L"expression", L"filename");
```

You don't need to do that for GetModuleHandle and FreeLibrary, because they're from kernel32.dll so you can just include Windows.h and call them normally.

Comment: How would be Pinvok in C++/CLI, can rewrite the above C# code to C++/CLI, I will be thankful.

Comment: I thought you did not want to use p/invoke. It's pointless from C++/CLI. You are better doing it the way you have attempted to do it. It's not hard to make it work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : previously I didn't want to use Pinvok, but because I tried your ways but I can't make it working with me. So I went back to Pinvok which I never used before. Thanks also for your answer, but actually I don't have `.lib` or `.h` files, all what I have is `MimTex.dll`.

Comment: It's really easy to create the .lib file, and you don't need a .h file. You just need the declaration in my answer. I think you are giving up too easily.

Comment: @Aan I updated the answer to show how the equivalent C++/CLI code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks a lot, I didn't know before that I can make `.lib` file from `.dll`, I searched and got the way, than applied what you explained in your answer and it works very well :) thanks again.

Comment: @user1610015 Thank you so much, your code is very clean and clear, I would try it as an alternative solution. A lot thank again :) +1

Answer (score 0):

There's a cleaner way of doing things:

Create a C++/CLI project. It will be your interface between C# and C++ (this is what C++/CLI is aimed at).

Make your C# project have a reference to this new assembly.

Inside your new C++/CLI project, configure project options so as you point to the directory with mimetex .h files for the compiler to compile your project, and the directory with .lib/.dll for the linker.

Inside your C++/CLI part, you just write C++ inside the functions. They are exposed to your C# assembly, but in the inside it's just calls to C++ functions as usual.
*(You should check a C++CLI tutorial to know what to do with strings to convert them to native char* or std::string. I remember I had to look at that.)*

In your C# part, you just call the C++CLI project assembly exposed functions like normal C# functions, without noticing it's native code called behind.